After switching from a public IP to an Elastic IP in AWS, my API page is no longer accessible, and Nginx is stuck on the "Welcome to nginx!" page
I initially set up an API on an Ubuntu virtual environment using Nginx, Gunicorn, and Supervisor, and it was working fine with the original public IP address. However, I decided to attach an Elastic IP to the instance. After attaching the Elastic IP, the API page became inaccessible, throwing 404 Not Found.
Steps Taken:
Updated all configurations that referenced the old public IP address to use the new Elastic IP, including:
gunicorn.conf,
settings.py in Django and
Restarted Nginx to apply changes, etc.
Configration:
AWS Security groups [Port range, Protocol, Source]: [22, TCP, 0.0.0.0/0], [80, TCP, 0.0.0.0/0], [80, TCP, ::/0]
Questions:
What could be causing Nginx to display the "Welcome to nginx!" page instead of serving my API?

Since you said you restarted NGINX and Django, did you restart Gunicorn as well? Try checking the NGINX configurations to see if they are correct with nginx -t (to test). If anything, restart the instance so that the configurations are "in fact" applied.
